# Fitting regular hexagons in some space

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Geometry is not my field of expertise and I need some guidance and references as to where I may go and read more about my problem.

The Program: To fit regular hexagons in some uniform shape.

So far I have come to [Truncated Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron), where 20 regular hexagons can be fitted. Although it has extra 12 pentagons they are fine. Other shapes used for glue are ok for my problem.

The issue I have with Truncated Icosahedron is that it is limited to 20 hexagons and I need to scale the hexagons to more than 20 (perhaps in thousands). Is there some neat other fitting (or perhaps in hyperspace) that I may look into, that shouldn't blow up in complexity (as in hexagons become more than 5000 or millions)?

Comment: You can't just use hexagons to form a "uniform" solid. To prove it, show that 1/ At every vertex, there has to be at least 3 faces, 2/ The sum of angles at each face is $< 360^\circ$, 3/ We can't have 3 hexagons meet at a vertex, neither can we have 2. Hence contradiction.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I am fine with using other shapes to glue the hexagons like pentagons used to create a soccer ball. Maybe what I am saying is that I need a soccer ball (or other shape) that has hexagons but more than 20 hexagons.